# How to add to a variable outside of the loop so that it remembers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a program where a car will accelerate by 5 or decelerate by 5 every time they input a "1" for accelerate, a "2" for decelerate, or a "3" to exit.

My problem is that the way that I have it setup at the moment is that it doesn't remember the speed after it goes through the loop once.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
def main():
    speed = 0
    question = int(input("Enter 1 for accelerate, 2 for decelerate, or 3 to exit:"))
    while question == 1:
        speed = speed + 5
        print("Car speed:", speed)
        main()
    while question == 2:
        speed = speed - 5
        print("Car speed:", speed)
        main()
    if question == 3:
        print("done")

main()
```

How do I make it remember the speed?

Comment: How about passing the speed as an argument inside the recursive definition of `main` and returning the value ?

Comment: Do you understand what recursion is? If not, then don't use it. In other words, there are better ways to restart a function than explicitly calling it again, reseting your values back to 0

Comment: You reset `speed` each time you call `main`. Assign `speed` outside of the function, and input it as a parameter. As @KarthikRavindra said, pass it as an argument in `main`.

Comment: By the way, you can replace `speed = speed + 5` with `speed += 5`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `main()` again. Keep one while loop that checks that the entered value is not 3 for exiting:

```
question = 0
while question != 3:
    # do checks for non-exit values (1 and 2) here
    question = int(input("Enter ..."))
```

Comment: This requires `question` to be declared before the loop

Comment: He does have it declared before the loop. I'll extend the answer if needed.

Comment: Well, `while` should probably be `if` in the question

Answer (score 0):

When you call main again, you have a new namespace, and are declaring new variables within that. Your values are saved, just just not where you think they are.

Alternatively, don't call your function again

```
def main():
    speed = 0
    while True:
        question = int(input("Enter 1 for accelerate, 2 for decelerate, or 3 to exit:"))
        if question == 1:
            speed = speed + 5
        elif question == 2:
            speed = speed - 5
        elif question == 3:
            print("done")
            break 
        print("Car speed:", speed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use recursion? You just need a while cycle, right?

```
def main():
    speed = 0
    question = 0
    while question != 3:
        question = int(input("Enter 1 for accelerate, 2 for decelerate, or 3 to exit:"))
        if question == 1:
            speed = speed + 5
            print("Car speed:", speed)
        if question == 2:
            speed = speed - 5
            print("Car speed:", speed)
        if question == 3:
            print("done")
    print("Final speed is", speed)

main()
```

As they mentioned in the comments, what happens is that you are calling main in each case. Therefore the environment of main is a totally new var environment where speed was set to 0 as in the second line of your code.

For your particular problem I think recursion is note necessary. However, if you would like to use it, then you must pass speed as a parameter.

Comment: I assume you don't mean to call `main()` in the conditionals - it's unnecessary and counter to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in which you do your calculations then return the final speed.

Beware, your code may break if the user enter non `integer` value. This is why in my example i'm using a `try...except` to catch the error without breaking the processing.

Also, beware that with this actual algorithm, the final speed can have a negative value, which is incorrect. You should add a test for this case to handle this issue.

```
def get_speed(speed = 0):
    while 1:
        try:
            # Here your program may crash and can give an error of type ValueError
            # This is why i'm using try ... except to catch the exception
            question = int(input("Enter 1 for accelerate, 2 for decelerate, or 3 to exit: ")) 
            if question == 1:
                speed += 5
            elif question == 2:
                speed -= 5
            elif question == 3:
                print("done")
                print("Car speed: ", speed)
                return speed # Return and save your speed
                break
        except ValueError: 
            pass
# You can initialize your begenning speed 
# or use the default speed which is equal to 0
# NB: output_speed will store the returned speed 
# if you need it for further calculations
output_speed = get_speed()
```